# How can I make a tab active on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, portfolio

I'm using jquery to create a tab-based featured content area on my website - http://www.gregmalkin.co.uk -  but am having trouble getting the first tab to be 'active' on load, and then the active state to change to the selected tab when it auto changes.

When I click on a tab it becomes active, but I want them to be set as active automatically.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I assume this tab plugin is pre-made?  Try just adding "active" to the class of the first tab from its source.

```
<li><a rel="0" class="tabSelect active" href="#Tab0">Tierra Latina</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe forcing the click on the pageLoad or in $(document).ready()??

```
function pageLoad(){
    $('#tabidtoset').click()
}

$(function(){
    $('#tabidtoset').click()
})
```

If you need the diferences between each one, read
[here](http://encosia.com/2009/03/25/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/)

I just checked that tab plugin, and set active on the one you want to see first should work.

```
class="tabSelect active"
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a hidden field on everypage with the tab id you wants to make the active on pageload.

```
<input id="hdnActiveTab" type="hidden" val="tab2" />
```

And compare the hiddenfield values with tab ids on dom ready function, if it matches with any tab, attach `class="active"` to the tab as shown below

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if ($('#hdnActiveTab').length > 0) {
        var tabID = "#" + $("#hdnActiveTab").val();
        $(tabID).addClass("active");
    }              

});
```